# Is there a way to dynamically set a parameter in a stored procedure to the result of a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I would like to be able to set a parameter of a stored procedure dynamically, based on the results of a SQL query. The stored procedure calculates the distance traveled between a particular date and today. That particular date could be different for each record in the database. (The date is calculated in a separate stored procedure.) See the example. [image]

The stored procedure has two parameters: `@DateFrom` and `@DateTo`. `@DateFrom` should be the date in the `DateFrom` column, which, as you can see, is different for every record. Is there a way to loop through or something and set the `@DateFrom` parameter to the value in the `DateFrom` column for each record? `@DateTo` will always be today's date. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Im not sure what you are asking.  You can do anything in tsql so you need to give some more data here.

Comment: You could use a [Table Valued Parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: i think you should use getdate() function

Comment: Is it possible to loop through and reset the `@DateFrom` parameter to each of the dates in the `DateFrom` column and do the calculations based on that particular date?

Comment: Yes it's possible.   Google SQL CURSOR for examples of one way to do it.

Comment: @TabAlleman Thank you. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I got from your question, it's my first answer to a post please excuses typos or code format

```
USE tempdb
GO

IF OBJECT_ID(N'Tempdb.dbo.#DataTest') IS NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #DataTest
    (
    ID INT IDENTITY
    ,Name VARCHAR(100)
    ,DateTo DATETIME
    ,DateFrom DATETIME
    )
END
```

GO

```
INSERT INTO #DataTest (Name,DateTo,DateFrom) VALUES ('DataValues1', '20151201',GETDATE() + 1)
INSERT INTO #DataTest (Name,DateTo,DateFrom) VALUES ('DataValues3', '20151203',GETDATE() + 2)
INSERT INTO #DataTest (Name,DateTo,DateFrom) VALUES ('DataValues5', '20151205',GETDATE() + 3)
INSERT INTO #DataTest (Name,DateTo,DateFrom) VALUES ('DataValues7', '20151207',GETDATE() + 4)
INSERT INTO #DataTest (Name,DateTo,DateFrom) VALUES ('DataValues9', '20151209',GETDATE() + 5)
```

GO

```
CREATE PROC #CalculateData
(
@DateTo DATETIME,
@DateFrom DATETIME
)
AS
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND,@DateTo,@DateFrom) AS DataResult
GO

DECLARE @Count INT = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM #DataTest)
DECLARE @DateToParam DATETIME
DECLARE @DateFromToParam DATETIME
WHILE @Count IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @DateToParam = (SELECT DateTo FROM #DataTest WHERE ID = @Count)
    SET @DateFromToParam = (SELECT DateFrom FROM #DataTest WHERE ID = @Count)

    EXEC #CalculateData @DateToParam, @DateFromToParam

    SET @Count = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM #DataTest WHERE ID > @Count)

END
GO
DROP TABLE #DataTest
DROP PROCEDURE #CalculateData
```